# HTML tag inside XML

Tags: html, xml, excel

I was wondering how I can put HTML inside XML nodes:

I am using this for my exporting of data to excel:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-16'?>
<ss:Workbook xmlns:ss='urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:spreadsheet'>
<ss:Styles>
<ss:Style ss:ID='alt'>
<ss:Interior ss:Color='#9dcc7a' ss:Pattern='Solid'/>
</ss:Style>
</ss:Styles>
<ss:Worksheet ss:Name='Quarter 1'>
<ss:Table>
<ss:Row>
    <ss:Cell><ss:Data ss:Type='String'>Column 1</ss:Data></ss:Cell>
    <ss:Cell><ss:Data ss:Type='String'>Column 2</ss:Data></ss:Cell>
    <ss:Cell><ss:Data ss:Type='String'>Column 3</ss:Data></ss:Cell>
    <ss:Cell><ss:Data ss:Type='String'>Column 4</ss:Data></ss:Cell>
</ss:Row>
<ss:Row>
    <ss:Cell><ss:Data ss:Type='String'>Data</ss:Data></ss:Cell>
    <ss:Cell><ss:Data ss:Type='String'>Data</ss:Data></ss:Cell>
    <ss:Cell><ss:Data ss:Type='String'>Data</ss:Data></ss:Cell>
    <ss:Cell><ss:Data ss:Type='String'>Data</ss:Data></ss:Cell>
</ss:Row>
</ss:Worksheet>
</ss:Workbook>
```

This codes actually works. it displays the data in excel. But I am having a hard time doing the formatting so I'm thinking that it would be more easier if I will use HTML in replaced to the `<ss:Table>...`

By the way, I used XML here because I am exporting data to multiple sheets.

Is it possible to put HTML inside xml?

Please help.

Thanks.

Comment: You cannot put HTML inside XML. You can only put XML inside XML (XHTML is a form of XML that resembles HTML as closely as possible, so *technically* you could use XHTML). However, it's highly doubtful that Excel can understand it. If Excel is your target, you will have to make do with the XML elements it understands.

Comment: @Tomalak: XHTML is HMTL, only without laxness ;) Seriously, you can write HTML5 that is valid XML, see dev.w3.org/html5/html-xhtml-author-guide/html-xhtml-authoring-guide.html - I agree with Excel input, but the question was about putting HTML inside XML. I doubt that Excel can handle HTML that isn't XML but can't if it is.

Comment: @Andreas XHTML is a very small sub-set of XML (i.e. an *application* of XML) that browsers happen to be able to interpret and render. It's still XML, though.

Comment: @Tomalak: Sure it's XML, that's why it works. But it's also still HTML.

Comment: @Andreas Okay. What's your point? :)

Comment: @Tomalak: The point is yes, you can put HTML inside of XML

Comment: @Andreas This is idle hairsplitting. You can't put HTML into XML because HTML does not conform to XML semantics. And XHTML is *not* HTML. Especially does the fact that XHTML can be included in XML *not* mean that HTML can.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is possible to put HTML inside XML as long as it is in the flavour of XHTML, because that's already XML itself. Be sure to close tags like <br /> and put attributes into quote marks and you're on the safe side.